# Cross-browser marker animation in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, style, animation, markers

Currently I'm trying to implement animated markers in OpenLayers.  I'm using PNGs for the markers, set by the `externalGraphic` style property on an `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector`.  I need to be able to make the graphic pulse, grow, blink, etc. which means controlling its size and position.

With the SVG renderer I can get a reference to the `image` element by using the Geometry's `id` property.  However with the VML renderer (IE8 doesn't support SVG) I can't seem to find a way to get a reference to the `rect` element, which is what (I *think*) I need to manipulate to do the animation.

Am I thinking about this wrong?  Can I change the feature's style on the fly?  Should I just use animated GIFs (ugh)?  `OpenLayers.Layer.Markers`?  Something else?

What if I could get away with *not* supporting IE8 -- is working with the `image` a good way to go?

Edit: I also need to support selection and clustering of the markers...